# Examples of "famous" proofs using parity of number of transpositions of a permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Charles Pinter in his "A Book of Abstract Algebra" claims that the fact that a permutation can be non-uniquely decomposed into either an even or odd number of transpositions (but not both) has been used extensively in proofs in various branches of mathematics:

"...A number of great theorems of mathematics depend for their proof [...] on none other but the distinction between even and odd permutations." Chapter 8, page 84, 2nd ed.

Can anyone give an example of such a significant proof?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure that it is used in a very tiny footnote to the classification of finite simple groups ...

Comment: [Zolotarev's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zolotarev%27s_lemma) is equivalent to Gauss' Lemma and can be used to prove Quadratic Reciprocity.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_group Alternating groups are groups of even permutations; anything that you need alternating groups to do depend on the distinction.

Comment: @lulu JH Conway gives a nice proof of Quadratic Reciprocity using the idea of Legendre/Jacobi Symbols as signatures of permutations in "The (Sensory) Quadratic Form"

Comment: @MarkBennet  I'll look that up, thanks.  Is it fundamentally different from the proof via Gauss' Lemma?

Comment: Thank you. I am especially interested in using algebra abstractions (groups, rings, fields, etc.) as proof devices in other areas of mathematics. If there is a book on this exact topic I'd be interested to hear about it (my background is in applied mathematics & computer science). Thanks.

Comment: The Conway sensory quadratic form monograph can be uploaded [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/conwaysens.pdf)

Comment: @JeanMarie The proof (following Zolotarev) is p127ff and doesn't require reading the rest up to that point.